# How to use variable in For-In AHK Loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, autohotkey

```
rLensDesign := "FT"
lLensDesign := "SV"

for tempLensDesign in Object(rLensDesign, lLensDesign) {
...
}
```

I am getting an error in `for` loop saying "Unrecognized action". I know I did not do

> Object(rLensDesign, lLensDesign)

right but documentation is confusing and I cant figure out how to fix it. My objective is to have values of rLensDesign in tempLensDesign in first iteration of the loop and so on.

Comment: The code works here. You're probably using an old version of AutoHotkey. Download one from [ahkscript.org](http://ahkscript.org/)

Comment: Thanks that was the issue, if u add as answer, I will select.

Comment: Strictly speaking that's not a code-related problem so I voted to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace keyword "Object" with "Array".

Comment: This solved the issue. Remember 2 more things: (1) Update AHK to latest version (2) Change to for index, tempLensDesign .... and then ignore index if you dont need it.